# How to create doc file using 'touch' command on terminal

Tags: command-line, files

I have created text file by using touch command on terminal.

```
touch file_name
```

But i want to create doc,ppt etc file. 
Can anyone tell me about the commands to create doc,ppt files or is there any option to change extension when i am using touch command?

Comment: You have most likely _not_ created text files but _empty_ files. If not, please elaborate. Hint to create empty Office files: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40227#c15

Comment: Yes,those are empty .txt files.
But i want to create .doc word file.

is there any way to use command like i use to create empty .txt file

Comment: an empty file can be anything you want it to be ... try `touch file.doc`

Comment: In Linux, the extension is worth almost nothing. You can `touch file.doc` to create an empty file with the `.doc` extension. However, I think you want to create “empty” valid Office files using the command line, right?

Comment: You can `touch filename.ppt` `touch filename.doc`and so on .. but the files are still just empty files. First when a program puts data in the files they they become Power Point or Document files. Files extensions have no special meaning in Linux.

Comment: Yes i want to create valid empty office files @ Melebius

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Soren A ! and all guys! When i input some data on that empty file(with .doc extension) and refresh the window ,its automatically created  office file!

Answer (score -2):

1. Use the desired extension when you are using the `touch` command:

   ```
   touch file_name.doc
   ```

   or

   ```
   touch file_name.ppt
   ```
2. Then open that file and input some data. It will be automatically changed into a valid office file.

Comment: In Linux extention does not matter so much. You can start creating it as a file without any extention. When you put some text in it linux will just allow to perform on this file operations, performed with text files. It is not like windows. Anyway, you can keep extentions just to remember to what type given file belongs.

Comment: As Josef says, you're not correct.  Actually, even in Windows, if you created a new file in Windows Explorer and gave it the filename "file_name.doc", you haven't created an empty Word document at all.

Comment: but the file's icon has been changed to the word or ppt.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this involves launching a GUI app, so it does not fully answer your original question to use command line. Have you checked the link I provided (https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40227#c15)? You could probably also launch LibreOffice using `loffice file_name.doc`.